# List Categories in a CMS Page

Tags: magento-1.9, cms, category-tree

Can anyone advise how to list categories in a CMS page? For example, we have a category for each brand in our shop. I would like to list them all in a single CMS page. I realise I could do this using HTML but I want it to be automated, so if I disable a category it is removed from the list on the CMS page.

I wonder if there's an extension that achieves this or whether it can be done using something built into Magento?

Thank you.

Comment: you want just the top level categories or all of them as a tree structure?

Comment: They are all located under the category 'brands' - and it would just be the top level categories under the brands category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cms pages do not allow php code.
You can create a template to display your content and you can include it in CMS page like this:

> {{block type="core/template" template="path/to/template.phtml"}}

And put below mentioned code in this file:

```
<?php 
        $parentCategoryId = 31;
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentCategoryId );
        $children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
        $children->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', $category->getId())
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)//get only active categories if you want
        ->addAttributeToSort('name');//sort by position 
     ?>
    <div class="brands">
                     <ul>
             <?php foreach ($children as $child){ 

                     $skin_url = $child->getImageUrl(); ?>          
                    <li><a href="<?php echo $child->getURL();?>" title="<?php echo $child->getName();?>"><img src="<?php echo $skin_url?>" />               

                    <span class="brand-name"><?php echo $child->getName();?></span>
                    </a>
                    </li>

            <?php   }?>                     
            </ul>
    </div>
```

Ho it will help you.

Comment: Adding that code to a CMS page doesn't give the expected result. Can PHP script be used directly in a CMS page?

Comment: The cms pages do not allow php code.
You can create a template to display your content and you can include it in the page like this: {{block type="core/template" template="path/to/template.phtml"}}

Comment: Thank you. Just a note for anyone else that the parent category ID in the script above needs to be changed to the relevant ID in your own store. In my instance this was a change of '31' to '5'.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK There is no build-in function for what you are asking.

You should create a CMS widget iterating your categories.

Here there is a nice tutorial on how to create widgets: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/custom-widget-development-in-magento--cms-23015

To get a list of your store categories you could use:

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
  ->getCollection()
  ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
  ->addIsActiveFilter()
  ->addLevelFilter(1);
```

Hope it helps.